# Source code required for AutoMapper version 1.0.0.155

Tags: automapper

I need source code for AutoMapper version 1.0.0.155

It would be helpful if you can share links from where it can be downloded.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is [v1.0.zip — Version 1.0](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/tags). It has revision version 155 as you mentioned.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answering. dll that build from source in the link have version number 155. There is 'Release' folder in zip file that contain AutoMapper dll. When i used this dll my application worked fine. But when i used dll build(in debug as well as in release mode) from source code, my application does not worked as expected. So question is, what is the difference between dlls build from source code and dll in 'Release' folder?